# Slow saving products after upgrade to MariaDB 10.4 (Magento 2.4.5-P1 and PHP 8.1)

Tags: magento2, php, database, performance, mariadb

Since we upgraded Magento to ***2.4.5-P1*** and moved to MariaDB 10.4 (now ***10.4.28***) and PHP ***8.1***, we are facing really slow saving of products in admin. Everything else is fast, like the frontend, and working in the admin area. This is only related to saving products.

This worked flawless before, and we haven't made any other changes at all to the server or the software, like adding new extensions.

We have enabled SQL slow log, but that ain't giving us any clues, nothing is logged when saving.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

**--==UPDATE #1==--**

I think this issue has something to do with MariaDB 10.4.28, and/or PHP 8.1, as nothing else has changed on the server. Either i misconfiguration of MariaDB, or an extension incompatible with PHP 8.1.

This is my current MariaDB 10.4.28 configuration, tuned with ***mysqltuner***:

```
[server]
binlog_cache_size               = 16M
expire_logs_days                = 30
open_files_limit                = 32768
table_open_cache                = 64M
table_definition_cache          = 8192
net_retry_count                 = 16384
key_buffer_size                 = 6M
max_allowed_packet              = 64M
max_heap_table_size             = 768M
tmp_table_size                  = 196M
query_cache_type                = 0
query_cache_size                = 0
long_query_time                 = 0.5
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 512M
innodb_log_file_size            = 64M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_write_io_threads         = 8
innodb_read_io_threads          = 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 2

optimizer_switch                    = "rowid_filter=off"
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
join_buffer_size                    = 2M
performance_schema                  = ON
```

Comment: Try disabling any custom modules and try again.  Look up the logs if there is some error happening.

Comment: I would double check slow query log is working.  Set long_query_time to 0 and verify you see results appended to the log.

Answer (score 1):

set this MariaDB settings

```
optimizer_switch=‘rowid_filter=off’
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
```

see https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/database-server/mysql.html as source

Comment: Thanks for your input, I already had these two lines in MariaDB.